# Maven build is not generating class files inside the jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I have a Java project, and I need to compile that using Maven and place the jar file inside Nexus path. so I have used below pom in the project level

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>MyParentGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyParentArtifactId</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../MyRelativePath/</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>MyGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <classesDirectory>src</classesDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>src</include>
                             
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.skip.deploy>false</maven.skip.deploy>
    </properties>
</project>
```

After executing this project in Jenkins it goes through successfully and the jar file is generated in Nexus as expected. But the problem here is it does not contains the class files of the project and shows only the things which is shown in below screenshot:

[image]

I'm not sure what exactly its missing here. Can someone provide your inputs if faced such issues ? Thank you !

Comment: Why did you configure maven-jar-plugin like that?

Comment: Follow convention over configuration and the configuration of the maven-jar-plugin is simply wrong. The classes directory contains the compiled classes and the includes should include only areas where compiled classes are coming from which is simply wrong because in `src/` the source code is located apart from that your source code should be located in `src/main/java/<packageName>` nor is the configuration of the jar plugin needed...

Comment: Could you please provide some sample like how could we mention the same in pom file for getting the class files in jar ?